# How to remove these horizontal lines from my UITableViews bottom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My am seeing a horizontal line at the bottom of my table views section. I don't is it default or i accidentally have done something to that.
Please see this screen shot for clarity.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i have figured it out. This is because of the delegate method, heightForRowAtIndexPath:
Once i commented that out, its gone.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the default, you've done that somehow. You've likely done it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Comment it out and see if it goes away.

Comment: Nope its still there..i think this has to do something with the sections because these are all setions.

Comment: Which delegate and datasource methods are you implementing?

Comment: -(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath                     - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView      - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section                                                  - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath                     - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: Are you setting the `separatorStyle` property on the table view somewhere? If so, get rid of it. If not, set it to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` somewhere.

Comment: Well you're doing something somewhere. Can't really help you unless you post your entire project.

Answer (score 0):

try setting your tableView background to the same as the views background, that should fix it!